# Directfb unimplemented error

Tags: linux, framebuffer, directfb

I compiled Directfb successfully and now when I run any example or any application of Directfb I get this error:

```
(!!!)  *** UNIMPLEMENTED [fusion_dispatch] *** [fusion.c:3937]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this by:

1. Login as root.
2. while running your application use `--dfb:system=FBDev`.
   For example `./myapplication --dfb:system=FBDev`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with qingy. More Details:

```
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] stderr logger process shutting down...
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]  (!!!)  *** UNIMPLEMENTED [fusion_dispatch] *** [fusion.c:3937]
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]     --> An invalid argument has been specified
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] (!) DirectFB/Core: Could not initialize 'system_core' core!
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] (!) System/DevMem: Please supply 'video-phys = 0xXXXXXXXX' and 'video-length = XXXX' options!
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] (*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Fusion Dispatch' (3910) [MESSAGING - OTHER/0] <8392704>...
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] (*) Direct/Memcpy: Using libc memcpy()
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] (*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2015-02-14 15:43) [ DEBUG ]
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]       ----------------------------------------------------------------
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]         (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]         (c) 2001-2013  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]         (c) 2012-2013  DirectFB integrated media GmbH
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.7.6 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Mar 14 18:04:32, qingy-DirectFB on tty1, [DEBUG] (*) Direct/Thread: Started 'SigHandler' (3909) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8392704>...
```

Add following to your .directfbrc:

```
system=fbdev
fbdev=/dev/fb0
```